# Capture all URLs in Sinatra except /admin/

Tags: ruby, sinatra, url-routing

I'm trying to create an action that matches all URLs except for the /admin/ ones. I also want to capture the URL that was entered, but so far I can only do the first bit.

```
get %r{^(?!/admin/.*$)}
```

That's what I've got so far. This will make sure I get all URLs except admin, but then how do I capture what the URL was?

Answer (score 2):

aha!

Figured it out :)

```
get %r{^(?!/admin/.*$)(.*)} do |content|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current path in `request.path_info`.